# postgresql unique index preventing overlaping

Tags: postgresql, indexing, constraints, unique

My table permission looks like:

```
id serial,
person_id integer,
permission_id integer,
valid_from date,
valid_to date
```

I'd like to prevent creating permissions which overlaps valid_from, valid_to date

eg.

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 2010-10-01 | 2999-12-31
2 | 1 | 2 | 2010-10-01 | 2020-12-31
3 | 2 | 1 | 2015-10-01 | 2999-12-31
```

this can be added:

```
4 | 1 | 3 | 2011-10-01 | 2999-12-31 - because no such permission
5 | 2 | 1 | 2011-10-10 | 2999-12-31 - because no such person
6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2999-12-31 - because doesn't overlaps id:2
```

but this can't

```
7 | 1 | 1 | 2009-10-01 | 2010-02-01 - because overlaps id:1
8 | 1 | 2 | 2019-01-01 | 2022-12-31 - because overlaps id:2
9 | 2 | 1 | 2010-01-01 | 2016-12-31 - beacuse overlaps id:3
```

I can do outside checking but wonder if possible to do it on database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unique constraint is based on an equality operator and cannot be used in this case, but you can use an [exclude constraint.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) The constraint uses btree operators `<>` and `=`, hence you have to install [btree_gist extension.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html)

```
create extension if not exists btree_gist;

create table permission(
    id serial,
    person_id integer,
    permission_id integer,
    valid_from date,
    valid_to date,
    exclude using gist (
        person_id with =, 
        permission_id with =, 
        daterange(valid_from, valid_to) with &&)
);
```

These inserts are successful:

```
insert into permission values
    (1, 1, 1, '2010-10-01', '2999-12-31'),
    (2, 1, 2, '2010-10-01', '2020-12-31'),
    (3, 2, 1, '2015-10-01', '2999-12-31'),
    (4, 1, 3, '2011-10-01', '2999-12-31'),
    (5, 3, 1, '2011-10-10', '2999-12-31'), -- you meant person_id = 3 I suppose
    (6, 1, 2, '2021-01-01', '2999-12-31'),
    (7, 1, 1, '2009-10-01', '2010-02-01'); -- ranges do not overlap!
```

but this one is not:

```
insert into permission values
    (8, 1, 2, '2019-01-01', '2022-12-31');

ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "permission_person_id_permission_id_daterange_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (person_id, permission_id, daterange(valid_from, valid_to))=(1, 2, [2019-01-01,2022-12-31)) conflicts with existing key (person_id, permission_id, daterange(valid_from, valid_to))=(1, 2, [2010-10-01,2020-12-31)).
```

Try it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=59d2e787c48dbaa1d94c2def10f26923)

Comment: Perfect solution! Now I have a time to do a tests - it's exactly what I need. I suppose, that I should do `create extension if not exists btree_gist;` for each database once?

Comment: Yes, the extension should be installed once in a database you need it in.